# PHP: HTML to PHP multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

Using xPath query, I am trying to extract HTML values and put them into an associative array in PHP. I am using a loop to get the rows and cells from the table. But, I can;t figure out how to get the cells in an array embedded within an array that represents the row. Basically, just transferring the table structure to an array. Ideally, it would help to assign keys for the cell data.

I tried combining $key as an array and a counter to assign key/value pair.   I and xpath at different points of the structure. I can get fill up the array but I am But I just can't seem to crack it.

```
$cells = array();
$cell_values = array();
$key = array("MM", "DD", "TIME", "WVHT", "SwH", "SwP", "SwD", "WWH", "WWP", "WWD", "STEEPNESS", "APD");
$i = 3;

while($i <= 5){
    $rows = $xpath->query('//table[@class="dataTable"][2]/tr['.$i.']');
    if (!is_null($rows)){
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
            $i++;
            foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                $cell_values[] = $cell->nodeValue;
                $dataOut[] = array_combine($key, $cell_values);
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Expected:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] 
=> [10] => 
[11] => Array ( [MM] => 02 [DD] => 17 [TIME] => 11:30 am [WVHT] 
=> 3.0 [SwH] => 0.3 [SwP] => 10.5 [SwD] => SE [WWH] => 2.6 [WWP] => 8.3 
[WWD] => SE [STEEPNESS] => AVERAGE [APD] => 4.4 ) 
//Next set of row data with $keys
[12] => Array ( [MM] => 02 [DD] => 17 [TIME] => 11:00 am [WVHT] => 3.3 [SwH] 
=> 0.3 [SwP] => 10.5 [SwD] => SE [WWH] => 2.6 [WWP] => 8.3 [WWD] => SE 
[STEEPNESS] => AVERAGE [APD] => 4.4 ) 
[13] => Array... etc.
```

What I Get:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] 
=> [10] => [11] => Array ( [MM] => 02 [DD] => 17 [TIME] => 11:30 am [WVHT] 
=> 3.0 [SwH] => 0.3 [SwP] => 10.5 [SwD] => SE [WWH] => 2.6 [WWP] => 8.3 
[WWD] => SE [STEEPNESS] => AVERAGE [APD] => 4.4 ) [12] => [13] => [14] => 
[15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] 
=> [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => [30] => [31] => [32] => [33] => 
[34] => [35] => )
```

Comment: Your keys should be between quotes : `$data['DD']`
Without quotes, PHP will try to use the (probably undefined) constant DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your keys as values in the `$key` array rather than keys, you can `array_combine` that with the values from the `<td>`s to produce the rows for your result array.

```
$rows = $xpath->query('//table[@class="dataTable"][2]/tr');

// define these as values so you can use them in array_combine    
$key = array("WVHT", "SwH", "SwD", "WWH", "WWP", "WWD", "STEEPNESS", "AMD");

$data = array();
$cells = array();

if (!is_null($rows)) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

        // get all the cell values from the row
        $row_values = [];
        foreach ($cells as $cell) {
            $row_values[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        }

        // combine the keys with the values for this row and add the row to $data
        $data[] = array_combine($key, $row_values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't Panic, Thanks for the drop. But I am having a problem automating the array_combine.

Comment: Oh, oops, I forgot to empty `$row_values` before the inner loop. Sorry about that!

Comment: Without reinitializing that array before the loop, every row would just be appended to it rather than replacing it

Comment: Ah, OK...unset().
foreach ($rows as $row) {
          $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $i++;
    unset($cell_values);
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
           $cell_values[] = $cell->nodeValue;
           $dataOut[] = array_combine($key, $cell_values);
          }
   }

Comment: That is it, Thanks for help, brother.